# how to assign value to variable from a list with for loop in python

Tags: python

I am trying to save multiple variable with for loop from a list, i tried the below method but it is not working . how can I achieve something like this?

I want something like this

```
x1 = ""
x2 = ""

list = ["car","bike"]
for x in range(1,3):
    for i in list:
        x{x} = i
```

so once the loop finish we can run

print(x1)

print(x2)

**result**

car
bike

how can I achieve something like this in this method or any other method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: The short answer is: Don't do this. Use a `list` or a `dict` instead.